# C# Word AddIn edit CustomXmlParts

Tags: xml, ms-word, word-addins

I'm trying to edit a CustomXmlPart but I don't know how.

I tried this:

```
        CustomXMLParts xmlParts = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace(@"MyNamespace");
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlParts[1].XML);
        foreach (XmlNode mainNode in xmlDocument.ChildNodes)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node in mainNode)
            {
                switch (node.LocalName)
                {
                    case ("SelAdrIndex"):
                        node.InnerXml = "1111";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

But it's not working

The only other way I know, is to delete the XML part and add the edit version.

Comment: There is missing something like "xmlParts.Save()" to save the xmlPart, but I can't find such option.

Comment: Take a look at the properties and methods of the `CustomXMLPart` object. Work directly with those, not a separate XML document. (Note: the Word API bases on the MSXML parser, not the .NET XML libraries.)

Comment: Ahhh, meister Cindy. Most properties are read-only so i can't use them. There are some methods, to select a node, but I still need to save them afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties and methods of the `CustomXMLPart` object provide the capability to directly manipulate the content of a Custom XML Part. There is no need to use a save method or anything like that - the manipulation takes place immediately inside the XML file.

Note that the XML capabilities mirror those of the COM MSXML Parser and not the libraries of the .NET Framework.

Example to locate a node or nodes, then read/write the data.

```
    private void btnEditCXP_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.app.ActiveDocument;
        string sXML = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><books><book><title>Test 1</title><author>Me</author></book></books>";
        Office.CustomXMLPart cxp = doc.CustomXMLParts.Add(sXML);
        Office.CustomXMLNodes nds = cxp.SelectNodes("//book");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(nds.Count.ToString());
        foreach (Office.CustomXMLNode nd in nds)
        {
            Office.CustomXMLNode ndTitle = nd.SelectSingleNode("//title");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(ndTitle.Text);
            ndTitle.Text = "11111";
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(ndTitle.Text);
        }
    }
```